# i need to add try in my python script but not sure how to go about it

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch

i need to add try to my script so that when the input is blank or wrong it says so without displaying a blank table but have no idea how to do it help would be greatly appreciated

```
import mysql.connector
from prettytable import PrettyTable
username = input('what user are you looking for?: ')
bd = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="comptes_linux")
cursor = bd.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE %s", [username])
resultat = cursor.fetchall()
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["User","Filler","Uid","Gid","Gecos","Home","Login"]
x.align["User"]  = "l"
x.align["Gecos"] = "l"
x.align["Home"]  = "l"
x.align["Login"] = "l"
x.align["Uid"]   = "r"
x.align["Gid"]   = "r"
x.add_rows(resultat)
print(x)
cursor.close()
bd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I entered an if statement and also "try:.. except" to prevent further errors:

```
import mysql.connector
from prettytable import PrettyTable
username = input('what user are you looking for?: ')
if not username:
    print("Please enter a valid username")

else:    
    try:
        bd = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="comptes_linux")
        cursor = bd.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE %s", [username])
        resultat = cursor.fetchall()
        x = PrettyTable()
        x.field_names = ["User","Filler","Uid","Gid","Gecos","Home","Login"]
        x.align["User"]  = "l"
        x.align["Gecos"] = "l"
        x.align["Home"]  = "l"
        x.align["Login"] = "l"
        x.align["Uid"]   = "r"
        x.align["Gid"]   = "r"
        x.add_rows(resultat)
        print(x)
        cursor.close()
        bd.close()
    except:
        print("Couldn't find ",username)
```

"If not username" should detect an empty input, as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: this will not help, as an empty input generates an error

Comment: @nbk I have now changed it. This will hopefully now work, though it is hard to answer as I only have the code that the user has provided.

Answer (score 0):

This will only proceed if you have any user name entered.

Also it detects errors and show you the error

```
import mysql.connector
from prettytable import PrettyTable
try:
  username = input('what user are you looking for?: ')
except SyntaxError:
  username = None
  print(username)
if username is not None and username != '':
  try:
    bd = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="comptes_linux")
    cursor = bd.cursor()
    rows_count = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE %s", [username])
    if rows_count > 0:
      resultat = cursor.fetchall()
      x = PrettyTable()
      x.field_names = ["User","Filler","Uid","Gid","Gecos","Home","Login"]
      x.align["User"]  = "l"
      x.align["Gecos"] = "l"
      x.align["Home"]  = "l"
      x.align["Login"] = "l"
      x.align["Uid"]   = "r"
      x.align["Gid"]   = "r"
      x.add_rows(resultat)
      print(x)
      cursor.close()
      bd.close()
    else:
      print("username not found")
  except Exception as e:
    print("error: " + str(e))
else:
  print("username is empty")
```